# Show that V=W1⊕W2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L_1$, $L_2$ be linear operators where
$$L_1=L_1^2, \quad L_2=L_2^2 \tag{a}$$
$$L_1L_2=0, \quad L_2L_1=0 \tag{b}$$
$$I=L1+L2\tag{c}$$

Show that $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$. ($W_1$ should be the range of $L_1$, $W_2$ the range of $L_2$).

I'm not sure what I want to prove that makes $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ true and why. I can manipulate vectors with these operators, but I haven't found it to get me anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to prove that $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ and $W_1+W_2=V$.

Comment: Showing W1 n W2 = 0 would be enough I think, because I have a theorem. Is this correct: Let L1v1=L2v2 where v1, v2 are arbitrary vectors, then (L1^2)v1 = L1v1 = 0, hence the intersection must be 0?

Comment: Thanks for your help too. That's what I needed to think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints:

- $L_1^2 = L_1$ means the operator is a projection. Same for $L_2$.
- Cross terms are zero, i.e. the images don't overlap.
- $I=L_1+L_2$, i.e. each vector in the space has a preimage.

Can you conclude $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ from these?

Comment: I posted my guess above, is that enough or am I incomplete or doing it wrongly?

Comment: @Jimmy this is OK. But you are also need the second part to prove $L_1^2v_1=0$. Third part ensures that the union is $V$. (Also, you should perhaps add the answer to the end of the question? Just a suggestion.)

Comment: You're right, I needed that part. I'm doing this too late at night, half asleep, haha. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Showing W1 n W2 = 0 would be enough I think, because I have a theorem. Is this correct: Let L1v1=L2v2 where v1, v2 are arbitrary vectors (hence this is the intersection), (L1^2)v1 = L1v1 = 0, hence the intersection must be 0? I only used part 1 so I feel like I'm doing something wrong.